# Getting Ruby syntax errors in a simple example/exercise

Tags: ruby

I am newbie to ruby. Below is my code where I am trying to find a value which has value true and put it into `values`. But getting error

```
possible_values =
    [
      'ABC',
      'DEF',
      'GHI',
      'JKL',
      'MNO',
      'PQR'
    ]
    
options = {
    "environment"=>"dev", 
    "status"=>"valid", 
    "abc"=>true, 
    "def"=>true, 
    "ghi"=>false, 
    "jkl"=>false
    }

options['values'] = []
possible_values.each do |val|
    options['values'] << val if options[val.downcase]
    options.delete("val") 
end

puts "values: #{options['values'}"
```

Error: `can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)`

Desired Output:

```
 options = [
    "environment"=>"dev", 
    "status"=>"valid", 
    "values"=>["ABC", "DEF"]
    ]
```

Comment: I think your interpolation is off.  You are missing a right closing bracket?  Shouldn't your puts be like this:  ```puts "values: #{options['values']}"```

Comment: What do you want if `options` contains `"xyx"=>true`? What if `"xyx"=>false`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I cannot even run your code, I get a `SyntaxError` at parse time.

Comment: It seems that you posted the wrong code, since the code you posted *cannot possibly* produce the error you posted. Please, provide a [mre] that accurately reproduces the actual problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three bugs:

1. Your `puts` line is missing a `]`:

```rb
puts "values: #{options['values'}"
#                               ^ should be here
```

2. You want to remove the `options` key after processing it, but you're always removing `"val"` instead:

```rb
options.delete("val")
#              ^   ^ extra quotes making this a "val" String
```

3. Again, you want to remove the `options` key after processing. The `possible_values` are all uppercase, and won't match the corresponding keys in `options` for deletion without a `downcase`. Taking #2 and #3 together, what you want is: `options.delete(val.downcase)`

After fixing all three of these, this is the contents of `options`:

```rb
{"environment" => "dev", "status" => "valid", "values" => ["ABC", "DEF"]}
```

which seems to be what you wanted

Comment: None of this fixes the OP's problem "can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)". In fact, the OP's code *cannot possibly* result in that error in the first place! (Actually, the OP's code cannot result in a runtime error *at all*, since it is not syntactically valid and thus can never run.) So, clearly, the problem is in code the OP is not showing us.

Comment: It's pretty common for a beginner to ask the wrong question. It would have been more constructive if you helped and _fixed_ the question.

Comment: The OP posted the wrong code. The code in the question *cannot possibly* create the error. Even ignoring the syntax errors in the code. How is anybody supposed to fix the error if the code that produces the error is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I see you wish to mutate (modify) `options`, as opposed to returning a separate hash, leaving `options` unchanged.

I would be inclined to write the code as follows, in part to facilitate the testing of `true_keys` and `options` (below), after `true_keys` has been computed.

```
true_keys = options.keys.each_with_object([]) do |k,arr|
  case options[k]
  when true
    arr << k.upcase
    options.delete(k)
  when false
    options.delete(k) 
  end
end
  #=> ["ABC", "DEF"]
```

We now have:

```
options
  #=> {"environment"=>"dev", "status"=>"valid"}
```

Notice that we cannot write

```
true_keys = options.each_key.each_with_object([]) do |k,arr|...
```

or

```
true_keys = options.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),arr|...
```

because that would remove elements of `options` whilst interating over it, a no-no. That is not a problem when iterating over `options.keys`.

One more step:

```
options.tap { |h| h['values'] = true_keys & possible_values }
  #=> {"environment"=>"dev", "status"=>"valid", "values"=>["ABC", "DEF"]}
```

See [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap).

Just checking:

```
options
  #=> {"environment"=>"dev", "status"=>"valid", "values"=>["ABC", "DEF"]}
```

One could alternatively write

```
options.update('values'=>true_keys & possible_values)
  #=> {"environment"=>"dev", "status"=>"valid", "values"=>["ABC", "DEF"]}
```

See [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`).

---

If `options` and `possible_values` were large it would be sensible to convert `possible_values` to a set as an initial step, as set lookups are much faster than array lookups, the latter requiring a linear search. This only effects the `tap` (or `update`) operation.

```
require 'set'

possible_values_set = possible_values.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"}>
```

Then with

```
true_keys
  #=> ["ABC", "DEF"]
```

the `tap` expression would become:

```
options.tap do |h|
  h['values'] = true_keys.select { |k| possible_values_set.include?(k) }
end
  #=> {"environment"=>"dev", "status"=>"valid", "values"=>["ABC", "DEF"]}
```